# How to show each slide under active slide with blur effect and the active slide with 100% width - Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swipe, swiper.js

I'm trying to create this slider with swiper
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOc6R.png)

My JS code:

```js
var Swiper_Leaders = new Swiper('.onx-swiper-leaders', {
            speed: 400,
            centeredSlides: true,
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            effect: 'coverflow',
            coverflowEffect: {
                rotate: 0,
                stretch: 20,
                slideShadows: false,
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
        });
```

My css:

```
.onx-swiper-leaders .onx-leaders .swiper-slide{
    direction: ltr;
    width: fit-content !important;
}

.onx-swiper-leaders .onx-leaders .swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active){
    filter: blur(3px);
    scale: .9;
    margin-top: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

.onx-swiper-leaders .onx-leaders .swiper-slide-active {
    filter: blur(0);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
}

.onx-swiper-leaders .onx-leaders .swiper-slide-active .onx-leader .onx-leader-info {
    display: flex;
}
```

My HtML:

```
                        <div class="swiper onx-swiper-leaders" dir="rtl">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper onx-leaders">
                                <div class="swiper-slide">
                                    <div class="onx-leader">
                                        <div class="onx-leader-img">
                                            <img src="assets/img/leader/leader-1.jpg" alt="Leader Image">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="onx-leader-info">
                                            <strong>Antonia Moore</strong>
                                            <span>Real Estate Coach</span>
                                            <p>
                                                Realtyna Inc is a reputable company that specializes in providing advanced MLS Theme for wordpress solutions to real estate professionals. Their MLS SYNC system is a great addition to any real estate website looking to integrate MLS data into their website.
                                                <br>
                                                What sets Realtyna Inc apart from other companies is their innovative technology and commitment to customer satisfaction. They offer a wide range of features and customization options to fit the unique needs of each client.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide">
                                    <div class="onx-leader">
                                        <div class="onx-leader-img">
                                            <img src="assets/img/leader/leader-1.jpg" alt="Leader Image">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="onx-leader-info">
                                            <strong>Antonia Moore</strong>
                                            <span>Real Estate Coach</span>
                                            <p>
                                                Realtyna Inc is a reputable company that specializes in providing advanced MLS Theme for wordpress solutions to real estate professionals. Their MLS SYNC system is a great addition to any real estate website looking to integrate MLS data into their website.
                                                <br>
                                                What sets Realtyna Inc apart from other companies is their innovative technology and commitment to customer satisfaction. They offer a wide range of features and customization options to fit the unique needs of each client.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide">
                                    <div class="onx-leader">
                                        <div class="onx-leader-img">
                                            <img src="assets/img/leader/leader-1.jpg" alt="Leader Image">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="onx-leader-info">
                                            <strong>Antonia Moore</strong>
                                            <span>Real Estate Coach</span>
                                            <p>
                                                Realtyna Inc is a reputable company that specializes in providing advanced MLS Theme for wordpress solutions to real estate professionals. Their MLS SYNC system is a great addition to any real estate website looking to integrate MLS data into their website.
                                                <br>
                                                What sets Realtyna Inc apart from other companies is their innovative technology and commitment to customer satisfaction. They offer a wide range of features and customization options to fit the unique needs of each client.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide">
                                    <div class="onx-leader">
                                        <div class="onx-leader-img">
                                            <img src="assets/img/leader/leader-1.jpg" alt="Leader Image">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="onx-leader-info">
                                            <strong>Antonia Moore</strong>
                                            <span>Real Estate Coach</span>
                                            <p>
                                                Realtyna Inc is a reputable company that specializes in providing advanced MLS Theme for wordpress solutions to real estate professionals. Their MLS SYNC system is a great addition to any real estate website looking to integrate MLS data into their website.
                                                <br>
                                                What sets Realtyna Inc apart from other companies is their innovative technology and commitment to customer satisfaction. They offer a wide range of features and customization options to fit the unique needs of each client.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                        </div>
```

But the result that I'm getting is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22xDq.png)

But it isn't what I want. I want the active slide to be to the very right part of the container and the 2 previous slides under it in a blur form.